# In new users's home directory create sub-directory with a specific group and permissions

Tags: linux, debian, users

Linux will copy the the contents of `/etc/skel` when a new user is created. I want to have a sub-directory in each user's home directory, `MyStevedore`. I want this directory to have the owner be the new user and the group to be the group `stevedore` with the permissions `drwxrwxr-x`. The user is not a member of the group `stevedore`.

Comment: what Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: And the reason the distro matters is because depending on the distro and how you are creating users there are methods to extend the user creation tools to run a script of your choosing.  For example on Debian-based systems `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` will be called when you run adduser to create an account.

Comment: this is where a little script-fu wrapped around useradd might do the trick. Certain other distro's have 'adduser' which is a bash script doing just that!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `adduser` to create the user, it will do most of the job, assuming you've created a directory `/etc/skel/MyStevedore` with your desired permissions. However on most systems `~/MyStevedore` will always belong to the user's primary group.

On Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu), once `adduser` has created the user, it calls `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` if it exists. You can use it to complete the job.

```
#!/bin/sh
username=$1 uid=$2 gid=$3 home_dir=$4
if [ -d "$home_dir/MyStevedore" ]; then
  chgrp stevedore "$home_dir/MyStevedore"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an if statement to the .bash_profile script in /etc/skel that will check if the folder exists. If it doesn't exist it will create it and set the permissions.

The first time a new user logs in the folder will be created.